# dataframe values converted as 'nan' after applied df.iloc()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> nan values

I ran into a problem after runnning: pd.DataFrame(), the whole data-frame became 'nan' (empty). I could not reverse this again. I also assigned the data-frame columns names, but their values also disappeared:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df = pd.read_csv('PuntaCapi.csv', header=None, sep='\n')
    df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
    df.to_csv("PuntaCapi.tab",sep="\t",header=None, index=False)
    print(df)

    Akim =df.iloc[:,0:1] 

    A= pd.DataFrame(data =Akim ,columns=['Akim'])

    veriler2 = pd.DataFrame(data = df, columns=['Akim','Kuvvet','Zaman','Soguma','Yaklasma','Baski','SacKalinliği','PuntaCapi'])
    print(veriler2)
```

Please view the following results from the above mentioned code:
[![Spyder View DataFrame code [][2]][2][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48kbx.jpg)

[There is no nan value into the csv file. But after .iloc[], entire dataframe became nan value. I have tried solve the problem but I could not.  I need help to solve problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFd94.jpg)  
enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question.

You read data using `pd.read_csv('PuntaCapi.csv', header=None, sep='\n')` and save it as df, but you modify df as `df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)`, which directly impact on the result.

Try this code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('PuntaCapi.csv', header=None, sep='\n')
veriler2 = pd.DataFrame(data = df.values, columns=['Akim','Kuvvet','Zaman','Soguma','Yaklasma','Baski','SacKalinliği','PuntaCapi'])
```

Comment: I have applied it. Then I received this error. 
                                                                                                                                          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1694, in construction_error
    raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (65, 1), indices imply (65, 8)

Comment: Oh. I found our mistake. PuntaCapi.csv is seperated by '\n'? The error message is related with the data (df) is not seperated well. Please check it.

Comment: I have received this msg. There are some float value into dataframe such ('0,6', '2,22'). Do I have to apply any additional code about it?                                                                                              raise ParserError(msg)

ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 5, saw 4

Comment: Change sep = '\n' to sep = ','